# Impact of static definition on performence and on code memory size and on data memory size?

Tags: c, static

I know that static definition (ex: `static int toto;`) is used in order that function or variable will be seen only in the local file and not in the whole source code.

I m wondering if the static definition has impact:

1. on performence on binary program execution ?
2. on optimization of memory size of code memory?
3. on optimization of memory size of data memory?

Comment: You question is extremely platform/compiler/linker dependent as the Standard doesn't specify any of those areas explicitly. Which platform/compiler/linker are you targeting? Which switches are you using to build your code?

Comment: Are you confusing static with external here?

Comment: it's static and not external

Comment: @JohnU: `static` could be considered the direct opposite of `extern`: With `extern` you tell the compiler that the variable is defined in another unit; with `statíc` you tell it that the variable won't be used from any other unit.

Comment: @Mario - The (main IMHO) point of `static` is that it retains its value between calls, which may cause unintended behaviour. This has the side-effect of permanently taking up memory, as the variable cannot be destroyed when the function returns.

I would say that's more significant than the implications on variable scope, and I'm not sure I like the sound of the original question as it suggests this is being relied upon to fix some sort of problem or conflict which should probably be fixed in some more robust way.

Comment: It depends on how you use `static` (variable within function or not) - two completely different uses (and in this case we're essentially talking about the "global" one only I think).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

static is just the way to make the variable or function visible inside a current translation unit (current source file).It means the `global static` variables are having `internal linkage`.

So of course building any executable in which every indentifier has internal linkage is litter faster because no external symbols or less number of external symbols have to be resolved by linker.

But It can not be said surely without knowing the platform , compiler and it's version,So it's just a general explanation

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible to answer in general, as it really depends on how smart your compiler is, how you compile, etc.

It might make it easier for the compiler to optimize your code (e.g. completely remove the variable or inline the function as it knows it's never called from the outside; even if you just compile this single translation unit). However, this really depends on the compiler and how the variable or function are used (e.g. whether it's always initialized before being used in a function).

So using it right it might have a positive Impact on execution time as well as code size and memory usage.

---

As for `static` variables within functions things can be completely different (as you might preserve the variable from previous call, which could prevent it from being removed).

Answer (score 0):

Giving a generalized answer is pretty difficult, because it depends on both the compiler and the use case:

> on performence on binary program execution ?

this depends if the value is determined to be constant, if so, its propagated & folded under high optimization levels. It also depends a bit if its static within a function or at a TU scope. At TU scope it would be treated the same as any other BSS allocated variable, there are just multiple copies. at a function level, the address indirection will add quite a bit of overhead, as compared to a stack or register local variable (L1 caching would however mitigate most of the overhead).

> on optimization of memory size of code memory?

It shouldn't affect memory size of code except for the case of function static variables, which can't be stack allocated and thus require memory address access which add the overhead for the address access for every store and load. actual size increase would be negligible under most system though.

> on optimization of memory size of data memory?

depends on how many copies are made, which depends on how many TU's its included in (eg: static header variables may be created for each TU the header is included in).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, as Mario pointed out, defining `static` a local variable, tells the compiler to preserve its value between successsive calls; this may have many effects.  Mostly, this variable becomes a "module global" var, hence does not go on the stack (I refer to embedded fw);

Another effect, is that if you are using `static` var inside a function called from different threads simultaneously, you get different (lower) RAM usage (and, of course, very different behavior).

Answer (score 0):

A general answer would be: "it can't make it worse, but it could make it better". static and const and such do two things - they restrict what you can do and they allow the compiler to make better decisions. The compiler doesn't have to make those decisions but it can so it can't hurt and if you're lucky it will help.